# How can I use a for loop to run regression?

Tags: r, fixest

My current dataset looks like:

```
N = 10000
wage <- rnorm(N)
educ <- rnorm(N)
age  <- rnorm(N)
tce  <- rnorm(N)

work <- rbinom(n = N, size = 1, prob = 0.05)
manu <- rbinom(n = N, size = 1, prob = 0.05)

id <- sample(10, N, replace = TRUE)

df <- data.frame(wage, educ, age, tce, work, manu, id)
```

`wage`, `work` and `manu` are my dependent variables, and the rest of my variables are my independent variables.

Currently, I am repeating the syntax, but just changing the outcome variable as such:

```
library(fixest)

model1 <- feols(work ~ educ + age + tce | id, data = df)

model2 <- feols(manu ~ educ + age + tce | id, data = df)

model2 <- feols(wage~ educ + age + tce | id, data = df)
```

Is there a way I can use a for loop to run such regressions?

Moreover, after running the regressions, I would also like to plot the coefficients of the regressions as such:

```
library(modelsummary)

modelplot(
 list(model1, model2, model3)
 )
```

However, since for-loops don't create new objects how can I plot the coefficients?

Comment: Your df is not created correctly, throws error: arguments imply differing number of rows: 100, 2, 0, 10000

Comment: @VYago apologies, that's been fixed now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple estimations is a built-in functionality in `fixest`. Use `c(v1, v2)` to run regressions across multiple dependent variables. By the way, this will also be substantially faster than looping.

```r
est_multi = feols(c(work, manu, wage) ~ educ + age + tce | id, df)
etable(est_multi)
#>                          model 1          model 2           model 3
#> Dependent Var.:             work             manu              wage
#>                                                                    
#> educ            -0.0060 (0.0031) -0.0009 (0.0023)   0.0204 (0.0139)
#> age              0.0018 (0.0028)  0.0003 (0.0030)   0.0092 (0.0053)
#> tce             -0.0013 (0.0027)  0.0036 (0.0020) -0.0174. (0.0075)
#> Fixed-Effects:  ---------------- ---------------- -----------------
#> id                           Yes              Yes               Yes
#> _______________ ________________ ________________ _________________
#> S.E.: Clustered           by: id           by: id            by: id
#> Observations              10,000           10,000            10,000
#> R2                       0.00117          0.00038           0.00175
#> Within R2                0.00083          0.00031           0.00082
#> ---
#> Signif. codes: 0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

Note that if you have the variables names in a vector, you can plug them in directly in the formula thanks to the [dot-square-bracket operator](https://lrberge.github.io/fixest/articles/fixest_walkthrough.html#formula-macros):

```r
depvars = c("work", "manu", "wage")
est_multi_bis = feols(.[depvars] ~ work ~ educ + age + tce | id, df)
```

You can find some documentation on multiple estimations in the [dedicated vignette](https://lrberge.github.io/fixest/articles/multiple_estimations.html).

Answer (score 2):

I can't replicate your example with the provided code. Neverthless, you can use a loop like this:

```
variable <- c("work", "manu", "wage")
datalist <- list()

for(i in variable) {
  formula <- as.formula(paste(i, " ~ educ + age + tce | id"))
  model <- feols(formula, data = df)
  datalist[[i]] <- model
}
```

The model for each condition will be saved in a list that you can access or extract as an object.

Comment: I am getting the error message: The right hand side of the formula (c("work", "manu", "wage")) contains no variable! Any ideas why this may be?

Comment: @anrisakaki96 Check the fixed code, there should be no more issue with formula format.